# Вывод информации в окно Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Продолжаю изучать Tinker и Sql. Пришла идея совместить эти две вещи. Проблема заключается в том ,что я сделал рабочую версию, но не то, что мне нужно. При нажатии кнопки зарегистрироваться/войти или же играть, текст выводится в терминал(т.к print()) Поискав в документации Tinker, я не нашёл ничего связанного с выводом текста.

```
import sqlite3
from random import randint
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
global db
global cu
db = sqlite3.connect('server1.db')
cu = db.cursor()
window = tk.Tk()

cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    win INT,
    cash INT
)""")
db.commit()
def menu():
    global user_login
    global password_login
    user_login = input('Ваше имя:')
    password_login = input('Ваш пароль:')
    cu.execute(f"SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
    if cu.fetchone() is None:
        cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (user_login, password_login, 0, 0))
        db.commit()
        print("Зарегистрировано")
    else:
        print(f"Добро пожаловать, {user_login}!")
        game()

def game():
    print("Чтоб начать игру, нажмите на кнопку ниже")
    tk.Button(window, text="Играть", command=game1).place(x=10, y=40)

def game1():
    number = randint(1, 7)
    for i in cu.execute(f"SELECT win FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'"):
        wins = i[0]
    if number == 1:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {1 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы выйграли!ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()
    elif number == 7:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {50 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы выйграли!ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()
    elif number == 3:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {3 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы взяли джекпот!ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()
    elif number == 6:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {-10 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы сломали игровой миханизм, ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()
    else:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {-1 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы проиграли, ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()

def show_image(path):
    window.title("Казино")
    img = Image.open(path)
    width = 500
    ratio = (width / float(img.size[0]))
    height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
    imag = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imag)
    panel = tk.Label(window, image=image)
    panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")
    tk.Button(window, text="Регистрация/вход", command=menu).place(x=10, y=10)
    window.mainloop()
show_image('')
```

Comment: Используйте многострочное текстовое поле `Text()`. См. например тут: https://learn4kid-python.firebaseapp.com/tkinter_2/tkinter_text/

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что вы написали `print("text")`
А надо в самом начале написать `import tkinter.messagebox as msg`, и заменить print("Зарегистрировано") в `msg.showinfo("Зарегистрировано", "Вы зарегистрированы!")`
или же

```py
import tkinter.messagebox as msg
import sqlite3
from random import randint
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
global db
global cu
db = sqlite3.connect('server1.db')
cu = db.cursor()
window = tk.Tk()

cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    win INT,
    cash INT
)""")
db.commit()
def menu():
    global user_login
    global password_login
    user_login = input('Ваше имя:')
    password_login = input('Ваш пароль:')
    cu.execute(f"SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
    if cu.fetchone() is None:
        cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (user_login, password_login, 0, 0))
        db.commit()
        msg.showinfo("Зарегистрировано", "Вы зарегистрированы!")
    else:
        print(f"Добро пожаловать, {user_login}!")
        game()

def game():
    print("Чтоб начать игру, нажмите на кнопку ниже")
    tk.Button(window, text="Играть", command=game1).place(x=10, y=40)

def game1():
    number = randint(1, 7)
    for i in cu.execute(f"SELECT win FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'"):
        wins = i[0]
    if number == 1:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {1 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы выйграли!ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()
    elif number == 7:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {50 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы выйграли!ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()
    elif number == 3:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {3 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы взяли джекпот!ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()
    elif number == 6:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {-10 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы сломали игровой миханизм, ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()
    else:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {-1 + wins} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        print(f"Вы проиграли, ваше число: {number}")
        for value in cu.execute("SELECT login, win FROM user"):
            print(value)
        db.commit()

def show_image(path):
    window.title("Казино")
    img = Image.open(path)
    width = 500
    ratio = (width / float(img.size[0]))
    height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
    imag = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imag)
    panel = tk.Label(window, image=image)
    panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")
    tk.Button(window, text="Регистрация/вход", command=menu).place(x=10, y=10)
    window.mainloop()
show_image('')
```